# Why and How are parts of different distributed by the same key tables turned out to be on the same segments?

Tags: greenplum

So my question is quite simple, however even though there's a LOT of information about distribution on the internet, I haven't found a single article nor video about HOW exactly chunks of distributed by the same key tables end up on the SAME segments?

Simply put for example I have two tables **table1** and **table2**  in the same database and in the same schema on the greenplum which has lets say 3 segments one for each segment node if it matters.
And both of these tables are distributed by the field **id**.

If i undestand corretly  for example  if all records  with the id=1 from the **table1** got into  1st segement, then somehow all records with the id=1 from the **table2** would also got into 1st segment? How greenplum "knows" which segment fill with which id?? Why wouldn't  all records with **id=1** from the second table go to segment 2 or 3?  I mean if it is not the case then how local join works anyway?

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: Check https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Greenplum/7/greenplum-database/admin_guide-distribution.html . Basically, the distribution is based on the hash result of the distribution key.